# bash script: started with $! instead of #! and got mysterious behavior. What happened?

Tags: bash

I accidentally started a bash script with `$!` instead of `#!` and got some very weird behavior.  I'm trying to figure out what happened.

If you try this script:

```
$!/bin/bash
echo Hello world!
```

you will get the following behavior:

```
$ chmod +x hello
$ ./hello
[nothing happens, get prompt back]
$ exit
exit
Hello world!
$
```

So it looks like this happened:

1. A new bash shell spawned.
2. Upon exit, the rest of the script executed.

What's up?  How is anything at all happening?  Without `#!`, how does the shell know to use `bash` to interpret the script?

Obviously this is a "satisfy my curiosity" rather than "solve my problem" question.  Googling does not yield much, probably because `#!` and `$!` in queries don't make the Google-bot happy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*$something* is a parameter *("variable")* expansion, but `$!` in particular returns a value that isn't set in your script, so it expands as a zero length string.

Therefore your script is, you are correct, the equivalent of:

```
/bin/bash
echo Hello world!
```

The [shebang magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is an old feature of Unix, but the shell is even older. A text file with the execute bit set that the kernel cannot exec (because it's not actually compiled) is executed by a subshell. That is, the shell deliberately runs another shell and passes the pathname as the parameter. This is how commands written as shell scripts were executed before shebang was invented, and it's still there in the code.

Answer (score 8):

dollar-bang gets the PID of the last backgrounded process.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html (Search for '$!')

Answer (score 3):

Expanding a bit on @DigitalRoss's answer:.

An executable script with no `#!` on the first line is executed by `/bin/sh` -- even if you execute it from `bash` (or `tcsh`).  This isn't shell functionality, it's in the kernel.

So when you executed your script, it was executed by `/bin/sh` (which means, on most systems, that it won't be able to use bash-specific features), `$!` expanded to nothing (because that shell hasn't launched any background processes), and the first line invokes an *interactive* `/bin/bash` shell.  Then you exit from that interactive shell, and your script execute the `echo Hello world!` line and terminates, putting you back in your original shell.

For example, if you change `echo Hello world!` to `echo $BASH_VERSION`, you'll find that it doesn't print anything -- and if you type `history` from the invoked interactive bash shell, it won't show anything.